# Error <52>: ldap_simple_bind_s() failed: Unavailable

Tags: windows, powershell, automation, active-directory, ldap

When i am trying to use simple bind to connect to Active Directory using LDAP protocol, i am getting following error:

```
res = ldap_simple_bind_s(ld, 'CN=test,CN=Users,DC=domain,DC=com', <unavailable>); // v.3
Error <52>: ldap_simple_bind_s() failed: Unavailable
Server error: 80090304: LdapErr: DSID-0C09044E, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 20ee, v2580
Error 0x80090304 The Local Security Authority cannot be contacted
```

the username i am using is = `CN=test,CN=Users,DC=domain,DC=com`

Please let me know how to resolve this issue. also let me know if any other info. required. Thank you :)

Comment: Which language / library / tools are you using? The code's not valid Powershell, so something else?

Comment: i am using ldp.exe to connect to active directory.

Answer (score 1):

The `data` value gives you the Windows Error Code. If you look that up [in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--8200-8999-), it's this:

> **ERROR_DS_INTERNAL_FAILURE**
>
> 8430 (0x20EE)
>
> The directory service encountered an internal failure.

I can't tell you exactly what that means, but it looks like something wrong with the domain controller.